# Delete row from Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-realtime-api

I am building a web app that interfaces with a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

I can successfully read data by consuming the JSON formatted version of the sheet.

I can successfully create *new* rows by posting to the /formResponse associated with the sheet.

**However, I am trying to figure out how to *update* or *delete* an existing row.   Is this exposed anywhere?**

I can not find any examples to do this.

Note: The sheet in question contains a field that is unique, so I do have something to match against should there be a way to update or delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Realtime API should not be used to modify file content. You should consult the Spreadsheet API directly, which will allow you to  extract and modify the data. More information can be found on this site: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

If you are willing to implement Node.js on you proyect, then you can use the following code that allows you to access, modify and delete content from Drive Spreadsheets: https://github.com/jpillora/node-edit-google-spreadsheet

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript examples in your first link.  .NET and Java are not an option for this site.  I can't install Node.js in the environment either.